# Sharing Facebook access token between iOS and website

Tags: ios, facebook, access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I have developed a PHP website where users authenticate via Facebook and I get and store their auth_token.

On the other side, I have started developing an iOS app where users will be able to authenticate via Facebook too. The auth_token, as you know, will be different from the one that I got in the website auth process (same Facebook app as in the website)

**My question is: can I use the auth_token that I got in the iOS app to make requests from the website? (same user, same app)**

The reason is that sometimes I want some actions to be performed from the mobile device (ie. update status) while others to be performed from the web server (ie. checking which friends of the current user are already registered in my website)

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, as long as you have a valid `access_token` for the specific user you can use it anywhere you want. Anywhere that you can execute an `http` request to Facebook and provide the correct parameters, you'll be able to make API calls on behalf of the user.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?access_token=XXX
```

This call should work regardless of where you execute it from.

Comment: Can you give any evidence to support your answer? Cause I have run into situations where the token fail because it was generated from mobile and being used on the server.

Comment: Are you sure that the token you're talking about didn't just expire? In any case, why are you transferring tokens from the client to the server? Why don't you just perform another auth request from your server?